# Report Writer for Linux (XML, PGSQL, PHP, LINUX)

Tags: xml, postgresql, reporting, lamp

I'm a developer on an open source ERP project, it's web based and as you'd expect we have a requirement to print various reports. We currently use ezPDF but it means having to set a ridiculously high memory limit / execution time, and that is still limiting us to how many reports we can print.

We liked the look of [rlib](http://rlib.sicompos.com/) however complications compiling it are making this an increasinly unjustified option, the same could be said for [Papyrus](http://www.treshna.com/papyrus). Our ERP application uses PHP and PostgreSQL running on a Ubuntu server (running 10.04 LTS).

Can anyone recommend a report writer that will run on the platform I've described, that takes an XML report definition and connects to a PGSQL database.

Comment: If you don't mind sticking with PDFs, you can also consider [an HTML-to-PDF program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178448/list-of-html-to-pdf-converters) instead of creating the PDF by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right so after a little bit or research we've discovered [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/), of which takes an XML of the data and an XSL for the formatting, this then generates a PDF output, far better than the ezPDF option we were using and quicker too.

We were a bit concerned about going for a Java application as we didn't want the complexities of setting up the Java / PHP bridge, especially if doing a remote installation. However it seems it works well just by passing the values using the `exec` method.

Comment: If anyone is reading my answer to my question, I'm no longer on the dev team for this app... but the HTML to PDF generators are much more advanced than they were back in 2010. I've just used [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) on a project and it worked very well. If only it existed 4 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/) with PHP and there's [instructions for using it with PHP](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/usingPHP.php).

Comment: I think you meant [this link instead](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/usingPHP.php) for the PHP instructions.